# SSRS - How to filtered dimension subcategories into a single group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm not sure if this is possible but I'd like to be able to return a set of figures bases on a set of subcategory dimensions.

To explain visually I'm using this MDX for my data:

```
    SELECT NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Freight]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
    [Product].[Category Name].&[Accessories]*
    [Product].[Product Subcategory Key].[Product Subcategory Key].MEMBERS*
    [Due Date].[Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].MEMBERS

    } ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works Cube];
```

In my report I set out my table like this:
[image: layout]

And for the product subcategory key I'm applying a filter like:
[image: filter]

So the preview of the report looks like:
[image: report1]

What I'd like to see the freight for accessories (20-29) in one line. Even if I take out the product subcategory key from the table but leave the grouping in I still get 4 lines rather than one.
[image: report2]

Is it possible to have Accessories (20-29) display in one line? I realise I could filer my dataset but I'd like to use this one to be able to then create another tables and show the Accessories (30-39). Rather than have 6 dataset, one would be better and just filtering it would be great.

Comment: can you show you expect result with image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could create the group manually and then use it instead of product subcategory key. 
In dataset properties >> fields tab >> add calculated field >> like:

```
=SWITCH(Fields!subcategory_key.Value = "26", "G1",
Fields!subcategory_key.Value = "27", "G1",
Fields!subcategory_key.Value = "28", "G1",
Fields!subcategory_key.Value = "29", "G1",
TRUE,Fields!subcategory_key.Value
)
```

Comment: I found I have an issue when there is no value in Fields!subcategory_key.Value, is there a way to check before adding it to G1?